# C++ rule of thumb for std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> vs std::vector<Object>

Tags: c++, object, pointers, memory, vector

I was just wondering if there was a rule of thumb to determine whether you should use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>` vs `std::vector<Object>`. I understand that the pointer route is used to prevent object slicing in inheritance, and that `std::vector` stores its items contiguously. When should I use one over the other? What `sizeof(Object)` should encourage a pointer?

Comment: What would your answer be for `std::unique_ptr<Object>` vs `Object`?

Comment: Well, pointers are 8 bytes and objects can be wayyyyyy more. However, objects do not have to be derefrenced and object semantics are easier IMO. Idk. That's why I asked lol

Comment: These are good points, which also hold for `std::vector`. Imo, `std::vector<Object>` should be preferred unless there is a real reason to use `std::unique_ptr<Object>` (polymorphic types, unmovable type, ...).

Comment: So I should opt for vector of objects rather than vector of pointers when not dealing with complex OOP?

Comment: I would say yes. That would be my preference. C++ encourages value semantics.

Comment: "complex OOP" things usually can't be copied or assigned anyway, so they are not suitable elements for a container. Note that when done properly, slicing is not a problem, because then an attempt to slice causes a compiler error.

Comment: If you have "heavy" objects you may also make the objects themselves take care of some of this to make objects cheap to move in any situation, not just in vectors. `class Heavy { struct payload { ... }; std::unique_ptr<payload> data = std::make_unique<payload>(); };` where `payload` contains all the member variables.

Comment: What @TedLyngmo describes is called "Handle-Body Pattern", I believe, if you want to research further.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's an interesting idea. Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Cool - I didn't know it had a name, but of course it does :-)

Comment: There are too many variables to give a simple rule of thumb. Are the objects cheap to move/copy? Is the memory access pattern important for performance critical code? Do you need to create multiple vectors containing the same objects?

Comment: One tip: if you want vector<unique_ptr>, you can use ptr_container in boost.

Answer (score 2):

I use vectors of shared_ptr or unique_ptr all the time. Its  nothing to do with slicing (for me) its because usually you do not want copies of your objects, and having vectors of them is a great way to create copies by accident. I see a ton of school assignment projects here where there are 3 or 4 instances of the same student object all with differently updated data.

Second copying pointers is usually cheaper than copying large objects, and vecors copy objects when they expand.

Finally using shared_ptr as the main access point for objects allows them to be in complicated graphs, a student is linked to many classes, plus is assigned various tutorsrs, and have id cards etc.

Comment: Given this info, when should I not use std::vector<smart pointer<object>>?

Comment: "copying pointers is usually cheaper than copying large objects" You can't copy a unique_ptr. In fact, vectors may move objects when they expand.

Comment: @Thicc - `vector<int>` is of course a lot cheaper than anything using pointers. Programming is an engineering exercise, where "it depends" is more common than "one size fits all".

Comment: @ThiccTheo use direct vectors for simple types (int,....), and strings